# PHP echo div class not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I am trying to hook a class from one of my plugins into another using the following PHP (inserted into my child theme's functions.php). When I inspect my code, I can now SEE the class, in the hook area where I want it, however the meta information that the class should display is not appearing on my actual site.

Can anyone help? TIA.

```
add_action( 'gfwa_before_post_content', 'hook_events' ); 
function hook_events() {
echo '<div class="tribe-events-event-meta"></div>';
}
```

Comment: Add a "die()"; inside the hook function to see if it's getting called.  If not, "hook" may be a reserved keyword in function names.

Comment: I'm sorry would you mind showing me where you want me to add it? I'm relatively inexperienced with PHP, and don't want to blow it up lol.

Comment: And I'm assuming I could just change the name of the function so that it doesn't include that word, right?